# $\left|\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}\right| \leq 1$, for $\text{Re}(z) \leq 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Could someone tell me how to show
$$\left|\frac{e^{z}-1}{z}\right| \leq 1,$$
for $\text{Re}(z) \leq 0$?

I can see the function is bounded, but I am unable to show this is bounded by $1$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one easy way is to use maximum modulus on a large square $S_M$ bounded by $x=0, x=-2M, y=-M, y=M$ and let $M \to \infty$; noting that $|e^z-1| \le 2, \Re z \le 0$ it is clear that on all segments but the imaginary axis, the function is bounded by $1$ since $|z| \ge M$ on those; on the imaginary axis $z=iy$ and expliciting the terms, the inequality comes down to $2 |\sin y/2| \le |y|$ which is just a version of the inequality $|\sin x| \le |x|, x\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Have you thought about the real case first?

Comment: Similar to @Conrad's comment, consider $|z| \geq 2$.  The triangle inequality suffices there, so in light of the maximum modulus principle and symmetry, it suffices to prove $|e^{it}-1| \leq t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, I got it

Comment: @conrad That is  an overkill. Simple argument: $|\frac {e^{z}-1}z|=|\int_0^{1}e^{tz}dt|$ and $|e^{tz}|\leq 1$.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Just typing the inequality in approach0 should give links easily.